# Is there a way to change a specific word in an p or a tag attribute in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

This is kind of a beginners question. What I'm basically trying to do is loop different words in an HTML page's header. For instance, I would want a header that says "Paint your car the color of _____" where the empty space loops through the different words of "red", "blue", "green", "purple" etc... I've been looking everyone, but I can't seem to find anything. If someone can point me to the right direction of a link or something, that'd be much appreciated! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that should help you out.

```js
const colors = ['red', 'blue', 'purple'];
const duration = 1000;
let index = colors.length - 1;
const element = document.getElementById('page-header-color');

function updateElementText() {
    index = index < colors.length - 1 ? index + 1 : 0;
    element.innerText = colors[index];
}

updateElementText();
setInterval(updateElementText, duration);
```

```html
<h1>Paint your car the color of <span id="page-header-color"></span></h1>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much, didn't seem to be that much more difficult than I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use span:

```
Paint your car the color of <span id="custom-text">____</span>
```

Then change the innerHTML of custom-text as needed.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp